# Multi-dimensional Array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In php we can create multidimensional-associative arrays like

```
 $item = array(
     "spec" => array(
        "more" => "smth"
    ))
```

And  iterate them through `foreach($item as $a => $b)`

I'm wondering if I can do the same thing including the iterating process in python

Comment: It sounds like you want dictionaries. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries
You can iterate through them in a similar way (also explained in the link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a dictionary (of dictionaries) like this (python 3):

```
item = {"spec": {"more": "smth"}}

for key, value in item.items():
    print("The key was '" + key + "' and the value was:")
    print(value)
```

Comment: Whilst `dict.items()` will achieve the desired functionality, it's not the *pythonic* way to iterate over a `dict`. `dict.items()` returns a *copy* of the dictionary; what you'd actually want to use is `dict.iteritems()`; this returns an *iterator*.

Comment: @Adam Mitchell no, since Python 3 dict.items() has the same behaviour as the old dict.iteritems() in python 2. Thats' one of the reasons I stated that this example was for Python 3.

Comment: With Python 3.6+, you can also use f-strings, e.g. `f'The key was {key} and the value was {value}'`.